# Issue in updating fields in an array of embedded documents Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Currently my User model looks like:

```
{
  _id: 'SomeId'
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Cena',
  book: [{_id:'xyz',title: 'a', author:'b', isbn:'10' },{_id:'abc',title: 'c', author:'d', isbn:'12' }]
}
```

After making an findOneAndUpdate query to `update isbn field of book object whose _id matches with req.params.id`:

```
router.post('/update_book/:id', (req, res) => { 
  User.findOneAndUpdate({'book._id':req.params.id},{book: {isbn: '15'} }, {new: true,'book.$': 
  1}).select('book').exec((err,doc)=>{
  console.log(doc);
  }
});
```

After above code my collection looks like:

```
{
  _id: 'SomeId'
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Cena',
  book: [{isbn:'15' }]
}
```

It actually delete all other book objects and also removes other fields of matching book object. Please help me to write `findOneAndUpdate` query correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the positional [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update only the element that matches the query.

Example:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({'book._id':req.params.id}, {'book.$.isbn': '15'}...
```

Comment: I'm facing one more issue with this problem...findOneAndUpdate updates that book correctly but gives me every book object as output although I have added `'book.$': 
  1` & `new:true`as option...

Comment: You need to use `fields` option. But you cannot use a positional projection and return the new document so you need to use `$elemMatch`. Something like: `{fields: {book:  {$elemMatch: {_id: req.params.id}}}, new: true}`

Comment: Positional projection are giving unexpected results now after executing this query more than one time....it's actually pushing same book object multiple times `{'book.$.isbn': '15'}`

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide more details?

Comment: Brother... Help me for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375310/issue-in-getting-subdoc-fields-in-mongoose