# How to project updated values only using findOneAndUpdate in embedded array Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Currently my User model looks like:

```
{
  _id: 'SomeId'
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Cena',
  books: [
  { 
   _id: 'xyz',
    title: 'a', 
    author:'b', 
    ratings:[
      {source:'source1', value:"8"},
      {source:'source2', value:"9"}] 
  },

  {
    _id: 'abc',
    title: 'c', 
    author:'d',
    ratings:[
      {source:'source3', value:"7"},
      {source:'source4', value:"5"}] 
   }
 ]
}
```

After making an findOneAndUpdate query to `update rating=>value of 1st book object(_id: "xyz") from 8 to 10 for a given source(say "source1")`:

```
  let up={
     'books.$[book].ratings.$[rating].value':10
       }
  let filter={
      new:true,
      'books.rating':1,         //I just want rating array of updated objects in it
     arrayFilters:[
        { 'book._id':'xyz'},   
        { 'rating.source': 'source1'}
        ]
    }
  User.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':'userId','books._id':'xyz'},up,filter).select('books.rating').exec((err,doc)=> {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(doc);
  }
```

My code updates the books=>rating=>value correctly but I can't get that updated rating of that book.
This gives me rating of all books with both updated and non updated values in it. Looks like:-

```
{
  books: [{ ratings:[{source:'source1', value:"10"},{source:'source2', value:"9"}] },
          { ratings:[{source:'source3', value:"7"},{source:'source4', value:"5"}] }]
}
```

I think the data of 2nd book shouldn't be there at all according to my code. I expect the follwing output:

```
{
  books: [{ ratings:[{source:'source1', value:"10"}] }    
}
```

Please help me to write `findOneAndUpdate` query correctly!

Comment: So you only want `{
  books: [{ ratings:[{source:'source1', value:"10"}] }    
}` or the entire Document with only that rating object?

Comment: `{ books: [{ ratings:[{source:'source1', value:"10"}] } }` only!

Comment: See my response below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```js
const updatebookSource = (sourceId, userId, bookId) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId, "books._id": bookId }, up, filter).exec(
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      let res = doc.books[0].ratings.find(rating => {
        return rating.source === sourceId;
      });

      console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 1));
    }
  );
};
```

This returns the updated object. Let me know if it works.